# Find sum of $n$ terms of the series $12+14+24+58+164+\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Find sum of $n$ terms:
$12+14+24+58+164+\cdots$
I have tried my best but could not proceed

Comment: Do you have a formula to generate the $n$-th term in the sum?

Comment: No sorry I don't have any formula

Comment: @GargiBanerjee, What is the source of this problem?

Comment: @Peter I suppose he missed a comment, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/898988/find-the-nth-term

Comment: the problem is given in a chapter of geometric progression of a book

Comment: What book is that?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by grouping terms and using the geometric sum formula:
$$2[\{6+(1-1)\}+\{6+(3-2)\}+\{6+(9-3)\}+\{6+(27-4)\}+\dots]$$
$$=2[6n+(1+3+9+27+...)-(1+2+3+4+...)]$$
$$=2\bigg[6n+\frac{3^n-1}{3-1}-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\bigg]$$
$$=12n+3^n-1-n^2-n$$
$$=11n+3^n-1-n^2$$

Comment: What is the motivation behind thinking this way

Answer (score 2):

$12 + 14 + 24 + 58 + 164 + \ldots = 2 ( 6 + 7 + 12 + 29 + 82 + \ldots)$

Is the next term $486$?

You should see the second difference multiply by 3 in each succession (i.e. the difference between the terms, factored by $2$, being $1, 5, 17, 53, ...$).

Did you notice that?

Comment: the first term is 12 not 10

Comment: It was a typo, I amended it by the time of your comment but thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @Bronshtein, Have you reached till the end?

Comment: Yes, $3^n - 1 + 11 n - n^2$

Comment: For completeness, considering I've given the expression for the sum of the first $n$ terms, the $n^{th}$ term is $2(3^{n-1} + 6 - n)$. Did you get that, Gargi Banerjee, from seeing the pattern in the second differences?

Comment: Since there are only 5 terms in the sequence, there are infinitely many patterns fitting them.

Comment: @Bronshtein, Can you please share the steps to find the $n$th term ?

Comment: yes please share the steps @Bronshtein